# Array initialization with {0}, {0,}?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, initialization

Say I want to initialize myArray

```
char myArray[MAX] = {0};  
char myArray[MAX] = {0,};  
char myArray[MAX]; memset(myArray, 0, MAX);
```

Are they all equal or any preferred over another?

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't only the last one initialize *all* of the elements, not just the first one?

Comment: No, they all initialize every element. In the first two, the first element is explicitly zero and the rest are implicitly zero; in the last one, they are all explicitly set to zero.

Comment: @edA: there is no such thing as "partial initialization" in C. An object is either totally initialized or completely uninitialized.

Comment: @Mehrdad - This is incorrect.  As an example, try this: unsigned int test[32] = {0xDEADBEEF};  // The array will only contain one element with 0xDEADBEEF in it

Comment: @BrianVandenberg: How does that contradict what I said?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They are equivalent regarding the generated code (at least in optimised builds) because when an array is initialised with `{0}` syntax, all values that are not explicitly specified are implicitly initialised with 0, and the compiler will know enough to insert a call to `memset`.

The only difference is thus stylistic. The choice will depend on the coding standard you use, or your personal preferences.

Comment: I think that you should state the difference between {0} and {}. Although the result is the same, the meaning is not. Also, without that info, it could lead someone to think that {1} will initialise all to 1, which is wrong (as stated in @Mehrdad answer).

Answer (score 49):

Actually, in C++, I personally recommend:

```
char myArray[MAX] = {};
```

They all do the same thing, but I like this one better in C++; it's the most  succinct. (Unfortunately this isn't valid in C.)

By the way, *do note* that `char myArray[MAX] = {1};` does **not** initialize all values to 1! It only initializes the first value to 1, and the rest to zero. Because of this, I recommend you don't write `char myArray[MAX] = {0};` as it's a little bit misleading for some people, even though it works correctly.

Answer (score 6):

I think the first solution is best.

```
char myArray[MAX] = {0};  //best of all
```

Answer (score 1):

Either can be used

But I feel the below more understandable and readable ..

```
  char myArray[MAX]; 
  memset(myArray, 0, MAX);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you always want to initialize with 0.

--> Your first way and 2nd way are same. I prefer 1st.

--> Third way of `memset()` should be used when you want to assign 0s other than initialization.

--> If this array is expected to initialized only once, then you can put `static` keyword ahead of it, so that compiler will do the job for you (no runtime overhead)

Answer (score 0):

You can use also bzero fn (write zero-valued bytes)

```
#include <strings.h>
void bzero(void *s, size_t n)
```

http://linux.die.net/man/3/bzero